# Computer Description Query

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Ok I am stuck on syntax. Figures. If anyone can help me with another good pair of eyes I would appreciate it. Below is my script and below that is the one liner that returns the value I am looking for. The script does not return anything though.

**Script**

```
$BBUIDS = Get-Content 'C:\working\ad\Userstest.txt'

ForEach ($Name in $BBUIDS)
{
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Description -like $("$Name")' -Properties *  -SearchBase "OU=Win10,OU=Laptops,OU=Computers,OU=MYDOMAIN" | Select-Object CN
}
```

**Working oneliner**

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Description -like "USERNAMEHERE"' -Properties * -SearchBase "OU=Win10,OU=Laptops,OU=Computers,OU=MYDOMAIN" | Select-Object CN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Description -like $("$Name")' ...
```

to:

```
$Name = "*$Name*"
Get-ADComputer -Filter {Description -like $Name} ...
```

**edit based on comments**

```
$BBUIDS = Get-Content 'C:\working\ad\Userstest.txt'
ForEach ($Name in $BBUIDS) { 

    $Name = "*$Name*" 
    Get-ADComputer -Filter {Description -like $Name} -Properties * -SearchBase "OU=Win10,OU=Laptops,OU=Computers,MYDOMAIN" | Select-Object CN 
}
```

Comment: Tried that and it returns nothing but doesn't error out. It should return 3 values.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Just tried that and got the error below.
Get-ADComputer : The search filter cannot be recognized

Comment: Did you put the `$Name = "*$Name*"` in your code as well?

Comment: Yes just below the BBUID line.

Comment: $BBUIDS = Get-Content 'C:\working\ad\Userstest.txt'
$Name = "*$Name*"

ForEach ($Name in $BBUIDS)

{

Get-ADComputer -Filter {Description -like '$Name'} -Properties *  -SearchBase "OU=Win10,OU=Laptops,OU=Computers,MYDOMAIN" | Select-Object CN

}

In the users file there are 3 example users. Two with Data populated in the Computer descriptions and one without anything.

Comment: Sorry it mushed everything together.

Comment: You did not really do what I told you. I've edited my answer. Have a look at it.

Comment: You're the man TobyU. I knew it was my syntax causing the issue. Just didn't know what I was doing incorrect. It makes sense that it should be below and I have no idea what the hell is the matter with my brain that I did not see it sooner.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell will expand variables inside quotes only if you use double quotes. This is described in the documentation about [quoting rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6#single-and-double-quoted-strings):

> When you enclose a string **in double quotation marks** (a double-quoted string), variable names that are preceded by a dollar sign ($) are replaced with the variable's value

You can test this out in a PowerShell prompt:

```
$Name = "username"
'This is wrong: $Name'
"This is right: $Name"
```

The output will be:

```
This is wrong: $Name
This is right: username
```

You will notice that PowerShell will even highlight the `$Name` when using double quotes, but not when using single quotes.

So in your case, you need something like this:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "Description -like '$Name'" -Properties *  -SearchBase "OU=Win10,OU=Laptops,OU=Computers,OU=MYDOMAIN" | Select-Object C
```

The single quotes inside the double quotes are OK. You just need the outer quotes to be double quotes.

Or,

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {Description -like "$Name"} -Properties * -SearchBase "OU=Win10,OU=Laptops,OU=Computers,MYDOMAIN" | Select-Object CN
```

Also, I notice you are using `-like`, but you are not using any wildcards (`*`). So does the `Description` *exactly* match the username? If so, you can get slightly better performance by using `-eq` instead of `-like`.

If it doesn't exactly match, then you should be using `"*$Name*"`.

Comment: Does the `Description` field match the username exactly (no extra characters)?

Answer (score 0):

you can use either of this, though the first one is more efficient

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {Description -like "*$Name*"} -Properties *  -SearchBase "OU=Win10,OU=Laptops,OU=Computers,OU=MYDOMAIN" | Select-Object CN
```

or

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties *  -SearchBase "OU=Win10,OU=Laptops,OU=Computers,OU=MYDOMAIN" |where-object {$_.Description -like "*$Name*"} | Select-Object CN
```

Comment: Tried that and it bombs out. It's supposed to return the values in the computer description with the username in it. If it's done as a single liner editing the name manually each time it works. The moment you try to do it in a script using a text file with usernames. It either bombs out or returns no values when it should. I am sure it is just a syntax problem that I have not thought about yet.

Comment: 'Description -like $("$Name")'  this part is not correct in your code.if it is working for single input then make sure that you are giving correct input.    try, printing output of $ Name each time .and sometime it may contain extra space with name for that you may try trim function.